# property pre does not exist on schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to detect changes in the document via `pre` hook but it typescript is giving me error that this property does not exist.

**following Structured style, not OOP**

```
// category.schema.ts
const categorySchema = new Schema({
    category_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    icon_url: { type: String, required: true },
    items_quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    items: [
      item_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      item_name: { type: String, required: true }
    ]

})

const Category: Model<Category> = model<Category>('Category', categorySchema);

export default Category;
```

Now I want to check for document changes on deletion of subdocument.

```
import CategorySchema from "../schemas/category.schema"; // schema path

router.delete('/:category/:item', async (req, res) => { // removes an item

   let itemsQuantity: number;
   let category = await CategorySchema.findOneAndUpdate(
       { category_id: req.params.category },
       { $pull: { items: { item_id: req.params.item } } },
       { new: true });

   // pre does not exist
   CategorySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
       if(category.isModified()) {
           log('changed');
       } else {
         log('not changed')
       }
   })

   const data = await category.save();

   res.status(200).send(req.params.item);
})
```

How to get or enable this `hook`, any suggestions?

Comment: Use `this`. i.e `this.category`. Beyond that, you need to actually give some context here. Show a schema and what you are trying to do and what you expect to happen. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, let me clear

Comment: update my question

Comment: That's the "model" and not the "schema" the `pre` definition belongs in the `categorySchema` where you have defined it with the schema types.

Comment: I have updated the code. I hope it is clear now. I have included the file name and path to require. I hope now it is clear that it is schema, not model